# Apply CSS to part of element?

Tags: css, mask

Is this possible?

CSS Masks allow some "sub-element-level" modification.

I am thinking of the new translucent docks in OS X Yosemite, and wondering if it is possible to do the same thing in CSS. It is possible to achieve translucency (using opacity, or background colors with an alpha), but is it possible to achieve blur of the underlayer?

Blur is possible on an element using zoom, but is it possible to blur only part of an element, say with a mask?

Comment: I think you would probably need to clone the element you want to blur, and then wrap it within absolute positioned element which you will move behind the element you want to be translucent, adjust position of the cloned element within the absolute el and then blur it... But if there is different way it would be great

Comment: Yep that sounds like it is making sense. Thank you.